# Can value of buffer change after destructor executes

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, object-lifetime, placement-new

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

struct Foo {
  char ch;
  ~Foo() { ++ch; }
};

int main() {
  static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == 1);
  char buffer;
  auto const* pc = new (&buffer) Foo{42};
  
  // Change value using only the const pointer
  std::printf("%d\n", +buffer);
  pc->~Foo();
  std::printf("%d\n", +buffer);
}
```

[<kbd>godbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/forcoMPGT)

I am not causing any UB as far as I can tell, but GCC and Clang disagree on the result. I think the output should obviously be "42 43". That is the case for Clang, but GCC thinks the output is "42 0". How is that possible? Who zeros out the buffer? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior, so neither compiler is wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt could you elaborate on what's undefined?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Compiler discovers  the result of ++ch is not used and omits the increment. You may change the behavior with `volatile char ch;`.

Comment: @S.M. then it would have printed 42 42?

Comment: Either way compiler hypothetically is allowed to `rm -rf /` your system in case of UB. Why are you expecting any explanation to UB?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Who said about unchanged values after the destructor? Compiler may do all what it wants with a memory after the destructor.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I noted that I didn't see how it's undefined.

Comment: After the `pc->~Foo();` if you were to `new (&buffer) char;` the buffer is now live, but is UB to access because it hasn't been initialized.  UB to access, it could have arbitrary garbage (or possibly trip an uninitialized memory access and ABEND ... depends on the platform), or it could have the droids you are looking for.  The old [hotel room](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/4641116) problem.

Comment: @Eljay My problem is that I often think of `char` as byte of memory rather than a proper object with its own lifetime and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your final line, the lvalue `buffer` doesn't access any object.

The `char` object that was there initially had its lifetime ended by reusing its storage for a `Foo`.  The `Foo` had its lifetime ended by invoking the destructor.  And no one created any object in the storage after that.

lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (which is what `+buffer` does, but passing `buffer` as an argument to a variadic function would too) is not permitted where no object exists.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior.  The storage for `buffer` has been reused for the `Foo` object you created, so it's lifetime has ended and you can no longer use it.  The relevent section of the standard is [[basic.life]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#1) with 1.5 being the relavent sub section.

> The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when: [...]
>
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o ([intro.object]).

Comment: Interesting. What if it was allocated though malloc? `char* buffer = (char*)malloc(1):`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Still UB because the `char` object the pointer points to will also have it's storage resused.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Same problem.  Note that you *can* store a char value to `buffer` legally (pedantically via `new (&buffer) char(x)`), because you do still have valid storage. It's just reading from it after killing the object that is UB.

Answer (score 2):

```
§6.7.3.5
A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the
storage which the object occupies ...[cut]
```

You are accessing `buffer` after its lifetime is expired.